# ReverseOneToOne not evaluated in django signal

Tags: python, django

I have two models :

```
class Content(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    content = models.OneToOneField(Content, related_name="article_content")
```

And a signal (declared in signals module, and connected through AppConfig.ready() :

```
def clear_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    print(sender.article_content.pk)

post_save.connect(clear_cache, sender=Content)
```

When I save a content, `AttributeError: 'ReverseOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'pk'` is raised

```
art = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
ct = art.content   # content exists
ct.save()
```

So my questions :

1. Why getting related descriptor returns the linked object instance everywhere but not in my signal
2. How can i access my related object inside the signal (without replacing my OneToOneField by a ForeignKey)

I've setup [minimal project](https://github.com/jmbarbier/r121insignals) reproducing this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sender` is the *class* that the signal is attached to, not the instance that is being saved. That is in `kwargs['instance']`, or you could accept the arguments directly:

```
def clear_cache(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print(instance.article_content.pk)
```

Comment: I'm so dumb ! Thx.